# execute php echo command if either of two conditions are false

Tags: php

I have a php file that basically serves up random text. the random text can have its vote incremented or decremented by 1 (one). if the net vote is negative, the text is excluded from view, else show the text. Now i want ONLY text posted within the last week to be considered, else, echo "nothing to show now!"

This is the code i have:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db;charset=utf8', 'user', 'pass');

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT vote FROM voting where item = ? AND timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 7 DAY)');
($stmt->execute(array($item)));
($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
if ($row['vote'] < 0) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id,username,tag,message,timestamp FROM mybq_post_txt where id = ?');
    if ($stmt->execute(array($id))) {
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))       
        {
            echo "<p>", "<span class='tagtext'>author: </span>", ($row['username']), " ", "<span class='tagtext'>timestamp: </span>", ($row['timestamp']), "<br>"; 
            echo "<span class='tagtext'>tag: </span>", ($row['tag']), "<br>";                                                                   
        }
    }
    echo "<div class='loginreq'>This Post has been Voted Out because it achieved a negative vote balance. It can be voted back in by achieving a positive vote balance.</div>";
    echo "<div class='loginreq'>NOTE: This post may have been voted out because it was misleading or offensive. vote-in at your own risk.</div>";
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id,username,tag,message FROM mybq_post_txt where id = ?');
    if ($stmt->execute(array($id))) {
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo "<div class='vot_updown2' id=" . 'vt_' .$table.($row['id']). "></div>";    
        }
    }
}
else
{               
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id,username,tag,message,timestamp FROM mybq_post_txt where id = ? AND timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 7 DAY)');
    if ($stmt->execute(array($id))) {
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            echo "<p>", "<span class='tagtext'>author: </span>", ($row['username']), " ", "<span class='tagtext'>timestamp: </span>", ($row['timestamp']), "<br>";
            echo "<span class='tagtext'>tag: </span>", ($row['tag']), "<br>";
            echo "<p class='image_container'>", ($row['message']), "</p>";
            echo "<div class='vot_updown2' id=" . 'vt_' .$table.($row['id']). "></div><br>";        
        }
    }
}
```

edit: code now shortened to most relevant parts.

Comment: Can you shorten the code to the most relevant parts? Also what did you try already?

Comment: i'll try and do that kingkero. i already tried splitting the original statements and adding an else for each, no luck :(

Comment: If you learn to separate your code from your HTML, things would work out better for you. Mixing PHP and HTML is not a good habit. I mean, it is fine to call functions and other control flow logic, but avoid putting your business logic directly into your HTML; then `require` and execute your business logic from exposed functions and classes.

Comment: ok yanick... still learning tho'

Comment: Learning code indentation helps a lot in understanding code too, especially if you show it to others. Also trying to simplify code usually makes it easier to understand. For example; why do you do `"<p>", "<span` and not `"<p><span`? It makes the code more complicated to read. I suggest you read up a little on coding style and maybe PHP best practices, that might help in your learning journey. Also, Re-read your question a few times - is what you want to do clear? Edit it if it's not. Good luck, have fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you're wanting to know if there were rows returned from your query (since the query already checks to see if there were entires from the last 7 days) and if so, display them, and if not, display your message.

To achieve this, you'll need something like this:

```
if($stmt->execute(array($id))){
    if ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        do {
          echo "<p>", "<span class='tagtext'>author: </span>", ($row['username']), " ", "<span class='tagtext'>timestamp: </span>", ($row['timestamp']), "<br>"; 
            echo "<span class='tagtext'>tag: </span>", ($row['tag']), "<br>";
        } while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
    } else {
        echo 'Nothing to show now!';
    }
}
```

Once the statement is successfully executed, it attempts to fetch the first row. If it's successful, it falls into a `do{}while` loop, with the same logic you had before. The difference is, if no row is fetched, then it will display your "Nothing to show!" message.

I also moved some stuff around to be a little more logical with the new code. Full code:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db;charset=utf8', 'user', 'pass');


$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT vote FROM voting where item = ? AND timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 7 DAY)');
($stmt->execute(array($item)));
($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
if ($row['vote'] < 0) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id,username,tag,message,timestamp FROM mybq_post_txt where id = ?');
    if($stmt->execute(array($id))){
        // if there is a row to fetch, get it
        if ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            do {
                echo "<p>", "<span class='tagtext'>author: </span>", ($row['username']), " ", "<span class='tagtext'>timestamp: </span>", ($row['timestamp']), "<br>"; 
                echo "<span class='tagtext'>tag: </span>", ($row['tag']), "<br>";
                // moved these echos in here so that it won't display if there are no rows
                echo "<div class='loginreq'>This Post has been Voted Out because it achieved a negative vote balance. It can be voted back in by achieving a positive vote balance.</div>";
                echo "<div class='loginreq'>NOTE: This post may have been voted out because it was misleading or offensive. vote-in at your own risk.</div>";
                // also moved this in here so it won't display if there are no rows.
                $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id,username,tag,message FROM mybq_post_txt where id = ?');
                if($stmt->execute(array($id))){
                    if ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        do {
                          echo "<div class='vot_updown2' id=" . 'vt_' .$table.($row['id']). "></div>";
                        } while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
                    }
                }
            } while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
        // if no rows, show this message
        } else {
            echo 'Nothing to show now!';
        }
    }
} else {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id,username,tag,message,timestamp FROM mybq_post_txt where id = ? AND timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 7 DAY)');
    if($stmt->execute(array($id))){
        if ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            do {
                echo "<p>", "<span class='tagtext'>author: </span>", ($row['username']), " ", "<span class='tagtext'>timestamp: </span>", ($row['timestamp']), "<br>";
                echo "<span class='tagtext'>tag: </span>", ($row['tag']), "<br>";
                echo "<p class='image_container'>", ($row['message']), "</p>";
                echo "<div class='vot_updown2' id=" . 'vt_' .$table.($row['id']). "></div><br>";
            } while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
        // if no rows, show this message
        } else {
            echo 'Nothing to show now!';
        }
    }
}

?>
```

**EDIT:** updated code with the else statement

Comment: this was only half of the code :)... no word on the other part that displays when the votes are positive... unfortunately, it still gives an empty page, like i was getting before...

Comment: Updated the code with the `else` part. It's essentially the same as the `if` part.

Comment: Wow thanks sams. you've really been of help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to redirect to the login page when there's no session and if is session, there's no username.

First it check is session is set, thats false , and then check if myusername exists, and thats false.

`if (!isset($_SESSION['myusername']) && $_SESSION['myusername'] == '')`

Comment: wwow mike i think you missed the question. i'm trying to echo a statement if either of two conditions are false! take a look at the shortened code!